# Error: Data should be a matrix or data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, caching, syntax-error

FULL EDIT:

A script that have always worked has begun to give me this error:

```
Error: Data should be a matrix or data frame
```

Even though the data I'm using are in a Dataframe format

```
> is.data.frame(Dataset)
[1] TRUE
```

The error comes up when I try to do a `For Loop`to impute some missing values

```
for(i in 2:length(Dataset[-1])) {
  Dataset[,i] <- impute(Dataset[,i], "random")

}
```

I've already tried to restart R,clear cache `gc(), rm(list=ls())`, restart my PC (multiple times,as my R does seem to have a problem with cache clearing), I even reinstalled Rstudio.

This is my script:

```
library(table1)
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyverse)
library(gmodels)
library(ggpubr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(lares)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
```

```
Dataset <- read.csv(.........., sep=";")

names(Dataset)[1] <- "ID"

Dataset <- as.data.frame(Dataset)
```

```
set.seed(1)

for (i in 2:length(Dataset [-1]))  { 
  
  Dataset[,i]<-impute(Dataset[,i], "random")
}
```

```
Error: Data should be a matrix or data frame
```

With one of your suggestion ( Dataset[,i] does not return a data.frame. Dataset[i] does), this is the result:

```
Error: Data should contain at least two columns
```

While with `Across(everything()...)` it does not impute anything, no errors, but viewing the data after running `Across`, it's the same as before..

And this is a sample of my dataset (i'm sorry this is the best I can do to import it):

```
ID  Gender  Age  var1   var2    Var3    Var4    Var5
A   0        13  30        0    1      32.7     49.57
b   0        18  50        0    1      47.85    
c   0            40        1    1      47.86    44.22
d   1        14  70        0    1      70.76
e   1        14  80        1    1      36.06    62.27
f   0        16  60        1           35.73    60.27
g   0        14            1    0      57.94    60.28
h   0        19  50        0    0      60.88    37.8
i   0        13  30        1    0      54.29    67.47
j   0        15  50        1    1      54.30    60.27
```

EXTRA: using mtcars

```
Dataset<- mtcars
```

```
set.seed(1)

for (i in 2:length(Dataset [-1]))  { 
  
  Dataset[i]<-impute(Dataset[i], "random")
}
```

```
Error: Data should contain at least two columns
```

Comment: `Dataset[,i]` does *not* return a `data.frame`. `Dataset[i]` does.

Comment: But what of considering all rows and columns? 

Anyway it gives back this: Error: Data should contain at least two columns





`for (i in 2:length(Dataset_TCI_Aseba_Meth [-1]))  { 
  
  Dataset_TCI_Aseba_Meth[i]<-impute(Dataset_TCI_Aseba_Meth[i], "random")
}`

there are 87 columns...

Comment: please try edited suggestion (didn't change the procedure though)

Answer (score 1):

using dataframe **Dataset** from your edited question:

```
## to help others reproduce the issue:
Dataset <-
structure(list(ID = c("A", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j"), Gender = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Age = c(13L, 18L, NA, 14L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 19L, 13L, 15L), 
    var1 = c(30L, 50L, 40L, 70L, 80L, 60L, NA, 50L, 30L, 50L), 
    var2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Var3 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Var4 = c(32.7, 47.85, 
    47.86, 70.76, 36.06, 35.73, 57.94, 60.88, 54.29, 54.3), Var5 = c(49.57, 
    NA, 44.22, NA, 62.27, 60.27, 60.28, 37.8, 67.47, 60.27)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))
```

this is your input dataframe **Dataset** (note the NAs):

```
## > glimpse(Dataset)
## Rows: 10
## Columns: 8
## $ ID     <chr> "A", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
## $ Gender <int> 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ Age    <int> 13, 18, NA, 14, 14, 16, 14, 19, 13, 15
## $ var1   <int> 30, 50, 40, 70, 80, 60, NA, 50, 30, 50
## $ var2   <int> 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
## $ Var3   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1
## $ Var4   <dbl> 32.70, 47.85, 47.86, 70.76, 36.06, 35.73, 57.94, 60.88, 54.29, ~
## $ Var5   <dbl> 49.57, NA, 44.22, NA, 62.27, 60.27, 60.28, 37.80, 67.47, 60.27
```

you need libraries {dplyr} and {Hmisc} (provides `impute()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
```

now do the imputation across all columns (= `everything()`):

```
Dataset_imputed <- Dataset %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                function(x) impute(x)
                )
         )
```

... there you go:

```
## > glimpse(Dataset_imputed)
## Rows: 10
## Columns: 8
## $ ID     <chr> "A", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
## $ Gender <int> 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
## $ Age    <impute> 13, 18, 14, 14, 14, 16, 14, 19, 13, 15
## $ var1   <impute> 30, 50, 40, 70, 80, 60, 40, 50, 30, 50
## $ var2   <int> 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
## $ Var3   <impute> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
## $ Var4   <dbl> 32.70, 47.85, 47.86, 70.76, 36.06, 35.73, 57.94, 60.88, 54.29, ~
## $ Var5   <impute> 49.57, 49.57, 44.22, 62.27, 62.27, 60.27, 60.28, 37.80, 67.47, ~
```

Comment: It does not return an error, but not every column is imputed...

Comment: You could try changing the first argument to `across` (the variable = column selection). In this case, the first column is omitted as suggested in your question, but options are numerous, e.g. `across(everything(), ...)` or `across(starts_with("parameter", ...)` or ... see: https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html

Comment: It does nothing....i'm desperate, I don't understand how a script stop functioning like this
the data are exactly the same as 2 days ago where everything was ok

Comment: I even use mutate_if wth mean or median, thinking maybe "random" was the problem,but the results is the same: the dataset is NOT imputed, as if R does not work on it
And every other script with other dataset does the same, even if they always worked

Comment: Please edit your question by supplying 1. an exemplary subset of your input data ("Dataframe"), 2. the code you're running and 2. which errors/warnings you subsume under "doesn't work". To protect sensitive data, use bogus values: `df  <- Dataframe[1:5, 1:5]; df <- df * 0 + sample(c(NA, 1:3), 25, replace = TRUE)`. Paste the output of `dput(df)` so that others can reproduce your data.

Comment: Done. I hope it's ok like this!

Comment: ...I'm gonna give up...using the exact same dataset, copy-pasting your script it does not work.... I don't know what to do
It does not impute... and, to make it worst, if I ever try to use the old for loop, it gives me the error "must be dataframe"....

do you think I have to uninstall in a deeper way R, Rstudio? No clue
(Thanks though for your answers)